# Which parameters does configuration.nix take?

Tags: nixos, nix

My `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` starts with `{ config, lib, modulesPath, pkgs, ... }:`, because that's what was in whichever example I copied. A quick search through [the NixOS manual](https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/), `man nixos-generate-config`, and `man configuration.nix` shows only examples with an even simpler `{ config, pkgs, ... }:`.

Removing the `, ...` and running `nixos-rebuild switch` doesn't help; it prints the following three times:

> error: anonymous function at /etc/nixos/configuration.nix:1:1 called with unexpected argument 'specialArgs', at /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos/lib/modules.nix:372:8

How do I figure out its arguments?

Comment: https://discourse.nixos.org/t/what-are-the-arguments-available-to-a-given-module/11838

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with a terrible hack:

1. Remove the `, ...`
2. Run `nixos-rebuild switch`, which prints

   > error: anonymous function at /etc/nixos/configuration.nix:1:1 called with unexpected argument 'specialArgs', at /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos/lib/modules.nix:372:8
3. Add the argument above (`specialArgs`) into the signature.
4. Repeat steps 2 & 3 until done.

This resulted in the following signature:

```
{ config, lib, modulesPath, pkgs, specialArgs, options }:
```

Hopefully someone knows a better way to get this information.